# загрузка больших текстовых файлов

Tags: delphi

Имееться несколько текстовых файлов, каждое более 4-7 гб. Их надо загрузить в Оракле (10g) таблицу. При этом надо проверит тип файла (ANSI,ASCII).

Answer (score 1):

Если текстовые файлы в формате CVS или с разделителем TAB, то рекомендую использовать PL/SQL Developer (Главное меню - Tools - ODBC Importer) - работает быстро.